# How this is true $(1-\sum_{i \geq 3}2^{-i}) = (3/4)$?

Tags: summation

I'm reading a paper [A comparison of two lower bound methods for communication complexity, P.43](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=243790)

$$(1-2^{-1}) \times (1-2^{-2}) \times (1-\sum_{i \geq 3}2^{-i}) = (1/2)(3/4)(1-\sum_{i \geq 3}2^{-i}) = (3/8)(3/4)=9/32$$

I don't know how $(1-\sum_{i \geq 3}2^{-i}) = (3/4)$? Or Is there something missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{i\ge 3}2^{-i} = \sum_{i\ge 0} 2^{-i} - 2^{-0} - 2^{-1} -2^{-2} = \frac{1}{1 - 1/2} - 1 - 1/2 - 1/4$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(1-\sum _{ i\geq 3 } 2^{ -i })=1-\left( \frac { 1 }{ { 2 }^{ 3 } } +\frac { 1 }{ 2^{ 4 } } +... \right) =1-\left( \frac { \frac { 1 }{ { 2 }^{ 3 } }  }{ 1-\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  }  \right) =1-\frac { 1 }{ 4 } =\frac { 3 }{ 4 } \\ $$

Comment: @Bttani Thank you so much.. it is well-undertood. I just realized that this is the geometric series ...